# Azure B2C SAML Policy Access URL For Password Reset

Tags: tableau-api, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am configuring Azure B2C with Tableau using SAML protocol. How do I expose the password reset user journey? I can't do it from the portal and the policy URL doesn't load in the browser either.

Comment: we are trying to configure Azure B2C with Tableau too but have been unsuccessful. Able to use Azure AD through AD Domain services but not Azure B2C. How did you achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a SAML SaaS app where the forgot password error cannot be handled, you can use this sample which embeds the password reset steps into the sign in journey.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset

Comment: Thanks Jas. I’ll give this a go.

Comment: Subjourney being in public preview, any concerns using this in production? @Jas

Comment: You could implement it without a sub journey if it is a concern. It’s essentially a big IF statement that can be reimplemented with lots of preconditions in the main journey.